# Include PHP file from parent sibling folder in word press

Tags: php, wordpress, include-path

I try to include some PHP file to another one by using `include` function.
It works fine when files are at the same directory that simply can do

`include (file.php)`

and if a file is in the child folder like

`include (folder/file.php)`.

but I want to make my root WordPress folder project cleaner then change the location of my template files to `pages-template` folder but unfortunately, I can't include files from another folder that are the sibling with  `pages-template`.
I try this

`include '../inc/package-save.php';`

but I got errors

`Warning: include(../inc/package-save.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

any trick to fix this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.
just put the `dirname(__FILE__)` function before the directory that I want to include.

This function will get the directory path that files that I write this function to it.

for example, if file be at `C:\xampp\htdocs\amt-master\wp-content\themes\wp-bootstrap-child` it returns this path

But as my case, I want to get the previous path to do that I should just put this function in the same function like this

`include dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/filename.php"`

then it will return this path

`C:\xampp\htdocs\amt-master\wp-content\themes`

then you can write remaining path.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following

```
include TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/package-save.php';
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I got this error  `Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\amt-master/wp-content/themes/wp-bootstrap-4/inc/package-save.php`

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with WordPress, you should use ***get_template_directory()*** like the following example:

```
include get_template_directory() . "/inc/package-save.php";
```